# AWS Glue RenameField and writing to bucket failing with Broken Pipe error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have json0 which is a dynamic frame with columns and nested columns. I have used both Unbox for outer flattening of nested columns and relationalize for deeply nested columns.
I have renamed the field using RenameField.apply to remove period(".") with "_" . And finally I am writing that renamed dynamic frame to the bucket, but writing renamed dynamic frame is causing Broken pipe error.
anyone with AWS data expertise out here with any solutions regarding this?

json0 = Unbox.apply(frame=cf, path="s3_path", format="json",
transformation_ctx="json0" + tn)

```
        json0 = json0.relationalize("json0", "s3//path")
        
        cf = json0.select(list(json0.keys())[0])
        
        df_relationalize = cf.toDF()
        for field in df_relationalize.schema.fields:
            cf = RenameField.apply(frame=cf, old_name="`" + field.name + "`", new_name=field.name.replace(".", "_"),
                                   transformation_ctx="renamefield_" + field.name)

   



        jsonBreakoutCol1 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame=cf,
                                                                        connection_type="s3",
                                                                        connection_options={"path": json_path},
                                                                        format="parquet")
```

Comment: what is df_relationalize return type ? Is it a dynamic frame or dynamic frame collection?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy it is dataframe, as I have converted using .toDF()

Comment: My bad what's cf return type ?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy I am not sure how to print that out?